# How to query a table by retrieving priority data and sort by order in SQLITE DB

Tags: android, sqlite

I am stuck to retrieve a query.
Currently I have a table called "HISTORY" table where I have fields and data like, for example...

### display_date | item_type

> 2014-10-05 |  0
>
> 2014-10-08 |  0
>
> 2014-10-07 |  1
>
> 2014-10-09 |  1
>
> 2014-11-05 |  0
>
> 2014-11-05 |  1

I would like to retrieve one month data from history table and order by display_date.
And also I would like to sort item_type field 0 then 1 if display_date is same.
My query statement is `select * from history where strftime('%Y-%m-%d',display_date)>=strftime('%Y-%m-%d','now') 
and strftime('%Y-%m-%d',display_date)<=date('now', '+1 month') order by display_date DESC;` 
My query only give me sorted display_date.

But I would like to retrieve one month data from history table and order by display_date.
And also I would like to sort item_type field 0 then 1 if display_date is same.

### display_date | item_type

> 2014-10-05 |  0
>
> 2014-10-05 |  1
>
> 2014-10-07 |  1
>
> 2014-10-08 |  0
>
> 2014-10-09 |  1
>
> 2014-11-05 |  1
>
> 2014-11-05 |  0

Please help me to figure out. Thank you.

Comment: `%d-%m-%Y` this is not the format of your date...

Comment: Sorry for my mistake,it was %Y-%m-%d. Let me edit it.Thanks.

Comment: I also try this, but can't work to get all records. The query only give me two records not all records.                                                               **select * from history where strftime('%d-%m-%Y',display_date)>=strftime('%d-%m-%Y','now') 
and strftime('%d-%m-%Y',display_date)<=date('now', '+1 month') group by item_type order by display_date DESC;**

Comment: `two records` which ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM history
WHERE display_date BETWEEN date('now') AND date('now', '+1 month')
ORDER BY display_date, item_type
```

[**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2ebcc/1).